# libcurl function: about function CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION

Tags: libcurl

I am using multi socket, however, I am confused with this API

```
int timer_callback(CURLM *multi,    /* multi handle */
                long timeout_ms, /* see above */
                void *userp);    /* private callback pointer * 
CURLMcode curl_multi_setopt(CURLM *handle, CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION, timer_callback);
```

and I know that when the timeout changed, the callback function are called, however, the first time we register the callback function, for example:

```
curl_multi_setopt(handle, CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION, timer_cb);
//and the callback function is 
int timer_cb(CURLM *multi, long timeout_ms,void *userp)
{.....}
```

the second paramenter timeout_ms value is what?  and I read the docs/example hiperfifo.c, and I see the log, this value is 1ms, how did this value come?

thanks

knuth

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION.html):

> CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION - set callback to receive timeout values

```
int timer_callback(CURLM *multi,    /* multi handle */<br>
                   long timeout_ms, /* see above *//<br
                   void *userp);    /* private callback pointer */
```

> This callback function will be called when the timeout value changes. The `timeout_ms` value is at what latest time the application should call one of the "performing" functions of the multi interface (curl_multi_socket_action and curl_multi_perform) - to allow libcurl to keep timeouts and retries etc to work. A timeout_ms value of -1 means that there is no timeout at all, and 0 means that the timeout is already expired. libcurl attempts to limit calling this only when the fixed future timeout time actually changes

Answer (score -1):

Once a easy_handle is added to multi_handle via `curl_multi_add_handle()`[in this case, whenever a `new_conn()` is available], an internal 'jumpstart' is provided by creating a timeout action with 1ms as the timeout value. 
Below comments from multi.c

```
/* Set the timeout for this multi handle to expire really soon so that it will be taken care of even when this multi handle is added in the midst of operation when only the curl_multi_socket() API is used. During that flow, only sockets that time-out or have actions will be dealt with. Since this handle has no action yet, we make sure it times out to get things to     happen. */
Curl_expire(data, 1);
```

The actual timer callback set with `CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION` is called inside `update_timer()` after `Curl_expire()`

Hope this helps.